# How do I ask someone for how long they studied in a school

Tags: grammar, phrase-request, sentence-structure

How do I ask someone for how long they studied in a school in the past? (The are not studying any more.) Is it

> How long have you studied there?

or

> How long had studied there?

or some other question?

Comment: I would just ask: *How long **did** you study there?*

Answer (score 1):

I believe "How long had you studied there?" is correct.

Other example: How long had you worked in Germany, before you moved here?